# Using mysql INSERT with PDO does not work and returns no errors

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a function:

```
function report_error($db, $uid, $companyid, $function, $input, $error ){
        try {
        $submit = new PDO("mysql:host=".$db['server'].";dbname=".$db['db'], $db['mysql_login'], $db['mysql_pass'], array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
        $submit->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt=$submit->prepare ("INSERT INTO error_log (companyid, uid, funct, input, error, datetime) VALUES (:companyid, :uid, :function, :input, :error, NOW());");
        $stmt->bindParam(":uid", $uid);
        $stmt->bindParam(":input", $input);
        $stmt->bindParam(":companyid", $companyid);
        $stmt->bindParam(":error", $error);
        $stmt->bindParam(":function", $function);
        $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "error: ".$e->getMessage();
            //report_error ($db, $uid, $companyid, "report_error", $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

When i call the function:

```
report_error ($db, $_SESSION['uid'], $companyid, "update_company_rate", "car_category: $car_category, rate: $rate, companyid: $companyid", $error);
```

Nothing happens: no error msgs, no warnings in http logs, nothing. The query itself works fine, whenever I run it with navicat or other SQL-client.

I had been working on this one for 3 hours and can't think straight anymore, please see what is wrong in here.

Comment: Asking  to see what is wrong in here is off topic. There is nothing much to see though - if there is no error then either insert was successful or a function never called

Comment: What happens if you put the MYSQL query (with dummy data, ofcourse)  into PHPmyAdmin, for example?

Comment: @GerritLuimstra He wrote **The query itself works fine, whenever I run it with navicat or other SQL-client.**

Comment: Can you confirm that the PDO statement code is being executed?